# Component attributes do not support complex content (mixed C# and markup) error message

Tags: c#-4.0, blazor-server-side

I am working on validation on a form in a blazor server application.
I created the component below that I am using

```
    @* Inherits from the original InputText component *@
    @inherits InputText
    @* Bind the oninput event *@
    <input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes"
           class="@CssClass"
           value="@CurrentValue"
           @oninput="EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString)" />

    @code {

    }
```

I am using the inputTextOnInput in this form

```
     <EditForm EditContext="@EditContext">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                <div class="mb-5">
                    <label for="projectnameinput" class="form-label">Name your project*</label>
                    <InputTextOnInput  class="form-control form-control-lg cust @pNameValidation" id="projectnameinput" @bind-value="projectModel.ProjectName" @onkeyup=KeyboardEventHandler />
                </div>
     </EditForm>
```

since I created this I started getting the error message below

Component attributes do not support complex content (mixed C# and markup). Attribute: 'class', text: 'form-controlform-control-lgcustpNameValidation

Do you have an idea of what this implies?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `class` attribute in your new component if you have declared a specific parameter for that.

```html
<InputTextOnInput  class="form-control form-control-lg cust @pNameValidation" id="projectnameinput" @bind-value="projectModel.ProjectName" @onkeyup=KeyboardEventHandler />
```

you need to remove `class` from above and pass it via `CssClass`.

Comment: Where is the cssclass located?

Comment: If you _do_ want to have extra css, look at attribute splatting and/or passing a parameter with the extra css as a property.

Answer (score 1):

## Recent update

Apparently this can be overcome by simply wrapping the `@` parameter in brackets. Go figure.

At my new employer they just do this and problem does not occur:

```
<InputTextOnInput 
    class="form-control form-control-lg cust @(pNameValidation)" 
    id="projectnameinput" 
    @bind-value="projectModel.ProjectName" 
    @onkeyup=KeyboardEventHandler />
```

## Previous Answer (also works with .Net 6, but not as simple)

Simplest solution, until they support it properly, is to use string interpolation as the class value. That makes it a single parameter to class, *which is supported*.

e.g.

```
<InputTextOnInput 
    class="@($"form-control form-control-lg cust {pNameValidation}")" 
    id="projectnameinput" 
    @bind-value="projectModel.ProjectName" 
    @onkeyup=KeyboardEventHandler />
```

Syntax looks a little crazy, as the `$""` has to be wrapped in `@()` to be parsed correctly, but this is the simplest solution I have found that does not require any extra properties.

### Update

Given the way Blazor syntax works you can also skip the outer quotes

```
<InputTextOnInput 
    class=@($"form-control form-control-lg cust {pNameValidation}")
    id="projectnameinput" 
    @bind-value=@projectModel.ProjectName
    @onkeyup=@KeyboardEventHandler />
```

Note: I have got into the habit of prefixing non-constant values with `@` and dropping the quotes. This seems to read better with syntax highlighting. The rendering takes care of adding back quotes as needed.

Comment: In .NET 6 for a style it works only with string interpolation: style="@($"color: #{FontColor}")".

Comment: @Alex34758 Thanks. Good to know there is some use for that too. Have edited to note that.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Blazor/Razor don't let you mix text literals and variables within an attribute value. So when you try and do

```
<InputTextOnInput  class="form-control form-control-lg cust @pNameValidation" id="projectnameinput" @bind-value="projectModel.ProjectName" @onkeyup=KeyboardEventHandler />
```

the class statement is invalid because it contains literals "form-control", "form-control-lg" and "cust" and also a variable "@pNameValidation".

My solution to this problem was to create a little method on a component base class which allows mixing the two things.

```
    public string Class(string classStr, params string[] objStrs)
    {
        var output = new StringBuilder();
        output.Append(classStr);
        output.Append(' ');
        output.AppendJoin(' ', objStrs);
        return output.ToString();
    }
```

now all I have to do is to write my line like this

```
<InputTextOnInput  class="@Class("form-control form-control-lg cust", pNameValidation)" id="projectnameinput" @bind-value="projectModel.ProjectName" @onkeyup=KeyboardEventHandler />
```

and by using params, you can also just add as many string variables as you want.